# When configuring the signingkey in my gitconfig file, should it contain the e-mail address associated with the GPG key or the key ID?

Tags: git, git-config

I'm currently using the e-mail address, but I've noticed that the GitHub documentation uses the key ID itself as the value for the "signingkey" property. If I have to use the Key ID instead of my e-mail address, should I use the one that's used to sign commits and is displayed under the verified badge on GitHub? I mean that "This commit was signed with the committer’s verified signature. GPG key ID: XXXXXXXXXX" thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same ID as what's displayed on GitHub, as long as you're looking at a commit made on your system and not (for example) a merge commit done on GitHub.

You can also see your key ID(s) in GitHub's user settings, under https://github.com/settings/keys - look under "GPG Keys" and be sure to get the key ID (the one labeled "Key ID") and not a subkey's ID.

Comment: Ok, so I need to use that instead of the e-mail address, right?

Comment: Yes, if only because key IDs must be unique on a given system.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can use either.  Git accepts any value that can be passed to the `--local-user` parameter.  If you have only one key with that email address, then using the email address is fine.

However, it is in general a better idea to use the full fingerprint (without spaces), which you can see at the command line with `--fingerprint --list-keys`.  That's because it's unambiguous (only one key will have the given fingerprint), and it allows you more control.  For example, if you want to sign with a specific subkey, you can use the fingerprint for that subkey with an exclamation mark suffixed to it and that will tell GnuPG to use that subkey.  If you don't specify a subkey in this way, GnuPG will pick a suitable signing key, which may be a signing subkey or the main key.

You *can* use a key ID, but it's trivial to forge key IDs because they're so short, so you might end up specifying a different key than you intended.  Using the fingerprint is unambiguous and thus recommended over using key IDs.  It's likely that a soon-to-be-published revision of the OpenPGP spec will discourage or remove the use of key IDs for that reason.